# Query on value of array elements (PostgreSQL)

Tags: arrays, postgresql, postgresql-8.4

The following query:

```
select unnest(Table2.L) as X, unnest(Table1.O) 
from Table1, Table2 
where Table1.code = Table2.code 
order by X ;
```

produces the desired results. I would, however, like to exclude (unnested) rows which match some value. Adding a condition to the query, such as the following:

```
and unnest(Table2.L) != '-'
```

obviously does not work. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If by `unnest(Table2.L) != '-'` you mean

> throw out all the unnested elements that are `'-'`

then use a derived table and filter out the unnested values you don't want:

```
select *
from (
    select unnest(Table2.L) as X, unnest(Table1.O) 
    from Table1 join Table2 on Table1.code = Table2.code
) dt
where X != '-'
order by X ;
```

If you mean

> ignore all rows from `Table2` where `L` contains `'-'`

then you can use the [`@>` operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html#ARRAY-OPERATORS-TABLE) to check if `L` contains a certain element:

```
select unnest(Table2.L) as X, unnest(Table1.O)
from Table1 join Table2 on Table1.code = Table2.code
where not Table1.L @> ARRAY['-']
```

or you could use [ANY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-comparisons.html#AEN17415):

```
select unnest(Table2.L) as X, unnest(Table1.O)
from Table1 join Table2 on Table1.code = Table2.code
where not '-' = any(Table1.L)
```

And do yourself a favor by forgetting that implicit joins exist, always use explicit join conditions.

Comment: I meant the first scenario in your answer, but thanks for the additional information too.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it:

```
SELECT x, y
FROM  (SELECT code, unnest(l) AS x FROM table1) t1
JOIN  (SELECT code, unnest(o) AS y FROM table2) t2 USING (code)
WHERE  x <> '-'
ORDER  BY x;
```

May of may not be faster. Depends on how selective the WHERE clause is. Run a quick `EXPLAIN ANYLYZE`.

Note that I untangled `table1` and `table2`, which are reversed in the example. If you are confused by all the clarity, try substituting `x` -> `y` in the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clause.

If you actually want to eliminate occurrences of `-` on both sides, add `AND y <> '-'`
to the WHERE clause - making it symmetric (no cuonfusion possible).
I would also `ORDER  BY x, y`, if x is not guaranteed to be unique, to make the sort order stable.

[Demo on sqlfiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/b1698/3)

Comment: There are ~350 rows which match after excluding the `'-'` rows. Your answer gives ~34000, so something is wrong somewhere :) I'm checking it now. Also, I was able to include additional columns from `Table2` in the query which "mu is too short" provided, but am not able to do so with your answer.

Comment: There must be some kind of misunderstanding. Added a bit to my answer to clarify.